# Why last name does not show in Knockout js sample

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am knock out newbie and have the sample code like the following

```
<p>First Name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName" /></p>
 <p>Last Name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName" /></p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function AppViewModel() {
     this.firstName = "First";
     this.lastName = "Last";
 }
 ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

When I run the code all I see is

FirstName: First
First

I do not see the lastname and also the first name repeated twice. I am using ASP.Net empty project to create a html file as the default page. I am using 2.0.0 version of knock out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
```

**Added** I just tried the above in the [knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) and it worked.

Whereas

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: lastName"/></p>
```

did not work and broke knockout effects after the `<strong/>` element. (On windows chrome browser.)

**Why the problem** I think the `<strong>` element was not originally created in the dom because it was a self-closed element. Then knockout came along and tried to add html content to it. Result: the html was displayed, but in a way that interfered with the subsequent knockout dom changes.

In any case: test on multiple browsers and don't use self-closing elements when they aren't normally expected. Eg `<strong/>`

Comment: +1 Yep. Many tags are not meant to be self closing, though many browsers will forgive you for it. However, that type of invalid markup will cause wacky errors like this. Just create an open tag and a close tag and you'll be good to go.